# Angular 5 MatSnackBar closes too quickly in .subscribe

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm calling MatSnackBar is a .subscribe block and I can't get the duration to work. The snackbar opens, flashes and then closes immediately regardless of the duration I try to set.

```
this._myService.patchUser(user)
          .subscribe(results => {
            this.openSnackBar('Updated User');
          });

openSnackBar(message: any) {
    const config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
    config.duration = 2000;
    this.snackBar.open(message, 'OK', config });
  }
```

Update: This version still has the flash but the duration works:

```
this._myService.patchUser(user)
      .subscribe(results => {
        this.snackBar.open('Updated User', 'OK', { duration: 2000, });
      });
```

Comment: How come it can flash, but stay 2 seconds ?

Comment: @trichetriche good question. it pops up quickly, disappears and then comes back for 2 seconds. It's not the same as the behavior on the example page: https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/examples

Comment: Are you dispalying several pop-ups ? Because what you're describing is a pop-up replacing another ...

Comment: @trichetriche excellent point. It does look like that. I’ll dive into it in the morning and see if the snack-bar is being called more than once. Thanks

Comment: No problem, keep me updated !

Comment: @beachCode have you fixed that issue?

Comment: Yes, it's resolved. I upgraded to Angular 7 and it the transition, the duration for snackbar now works. I can't say exactly what fixed it though. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Angular 7 and in the transition, the duration for snackbar now works. I can't say exactly what fixed it though.